# Python - Extract from list and reshape

Tags: python

I have a list which holds `no_classes` elements, where each element is a numpy array of shape `no_people` x 2.

As an example, this list called `scores` is built with

```
no_classes = 3
no_people = 2
```

I wish to extract from this the second element for each person (always just the second one) and reshape into a matrix of shape `no_people` x `no_classes`

```
scores=[np.array([[1,2],[3,4]]),np.array([[5,6],[7,8]]),np.array([[9,10],[11,12]])]
```

For scores, this would result in the following matrix:

[image]

Any ideas how best to approach?

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the approaches:

```
a=[x[:,1] for x in scores]

for i,el in enumerate(a):
    if i ==0:
        hold=el
    else:
        hold=np.column_stack([hold,el])
```